# Saving and retrieving search filter

Tags: php, json, serialization

I am trying to save search filter and restore it upon user selection,

For example,

There is search car page,

The inputs are:

```
Car Name
Car Model
Car Maker
Car Year
Car Mileage
Car Owner
```

I need to allow user to save search filter, for example, a user can save

```
Car Name : 5 Series
Car Model: BMW
Car Maker: -
Car Year: -
```

So they can save this `search filter` and then use this filter to restore it.

I currently using jquery to serialize all input and save into database using `json_encode`, now my question would be how can i can use json_encoded data retrieved from database to restore it back?

Save data on MySQL:
`{"Car":{"car_id":"","car_name":"e60","car_model":"5series","car_maker":"bmw","car_year":""}}`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get the object back from its JSON-serialized form.

However, JSON doesn't store all of the information that PHP does.  If you don't need the JSON version for anything outside of PHP-land, you might consider just straight [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).  Better yet would be to use a form that fits in your database so you can query on it later, if needed.